# WPF xaml failed to load my control from my DLL

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, autodesk-navisworks

I am now working on secondary development of Autodesk Navisworks.
The xaml looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="SCA.EmergencySystem.Gui.MainFrame.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
        xmlns:nc="clr-namespace:SCA.EmergencySystem.NavisInterface.NavisControl;assembly=SCA.EmergencySystem.NavisInterface.NavisControl"
        Height="577.33" Width="879.502" Closed="on_Window_Closed" ShowInTaskbar="False" Title="EmergencySystem">
    <DockPanel>
        <WindowsFormsHost>
            <nc:NavisViewControl x:Uid="viewControl" x:Name="viewControl" Dock="Fill"/>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

It seems visual studio succeeded to recognize this line:

> xmlns:nc="clr-namespace:SCA.EmergencySystem.NavisInterface.NavisControl;assembly=SCA.EmergencySystem.NavisInterface.NavisControl"

So I think the namespace and assembly are both all right

However, the XAML failed to findout the name of my control that has already been defined in NavisControl.DLL which was loaded to the WPF project. `NavisViewControl` that derived from `System.Windows.Forms.Control` and  `Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Controls` is what I have developed. `nc:NavisViewControl` is not recognized.

Code of NavisViewControl is simple:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Controls;

namespace SCA.EmergencySystem.NavisInterface.NavisControl
{
    public class NavisViewControl : ViewControl
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the assembly name of NavisViewControl is "SCA.EmergencySystem.NavisInterface.NavisControl"?

Comment: Yes, it is defined in AssemblyInfo.cs

[assembly: AssemblyTitle("SCA.EmergencySystem.NavisInterface.NavisControl")]

Comment: You should check/change the namespace from project settings. It is not same with AssemblyInfo.cs. And you should use that assembly name.

Comment: I renamed the DLL to SCA.EmergencySystem.NavisInterface.NavisControl.dll and this problem is resolved, thanks :)

Comment: Is NavisControl.DLL developed for Windows Forms?

Comment: It seems API of navisworks2014 only supplies winform type control, so my DLL is winform type too.